# Opayo (SagePay) Amex payments fail since 3DSv2 (Using Direct V4)

Tags: opayo, 3d-secure

Is anybody else having issues taking Amex payments with Opayo (SagePay) Direct protocol V4 since the 6th July?

Everything was fine before then, seems to be related to 3DSv2 but I'm successfully using the V4 protocol and taking 3DSv2 payments against Visa/Mastercard.

I get all the way through the transaction including successfully completing the 3DSv2/Safekey pages and then when I pass the CRes back to Opayo I get a "5086 : Unexpected CRes" response

When I base64 decode the CRes I get the below. (trimmed to remove full ID's)

```
{"threeDSServerTransID":"5bfe447a-5443-...","acsTransID":"00f9a54d-84f0-...","messageType":"CRes","messageVersion":"2.1.0","transStatus":"N"}
```

The data I send to SafeKey looks like the below (form auto submits with JS) threeDSSessionData is the VPSTxID base64 encoded including the {} brackets

```
<form name="form" action="https://acs-safekey.americanexpress.com/GravityACS/processing3ds" method="POST"> 
<input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value="https://...?action=return3d&amp;VendorTxCode=XXX">
<input type="hidden" name="creq" value="ewog...ICIwMiIKfQ">
<input type="hidden" name="threeDSSessionData" value="ezg1NTA5MzM.......UU1OH0=">
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Continue"> 
</form>
```

The transStatus:N response makes me wonder if its something on the way to SafeKey and Opayo aren't handling the decline? i.e. is it because I'm doing the following and hence they are declining the transaction - but then wouldn't it do that before it got to 3DS?

```
COFUsage=FIRST&InitiatedType=CIT&MITType=UNSCHEDULED
```

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Amex transactions magically started processing successfully yesterday with no further changes from me! Looks like it was an Opayo issue. Not sure why they couldn't have been transparent about that, terrible service, I have wasted hours on this chasing them and jumping through hoops making changes they suggested that weren't necessary!